# How to open steampipe dashboard on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, steampipe

I am trying to open steampipe dashboard on AWS EC2, when i execute the command "steampipe dashbaord", it fails at the step "Opening web browser". I understand that steampipe is looking for web browser but i want to ask if there is any way to view the dashboard the way we view Grafana Dashbaord by opening the port in security group?

Or should i have a UI based OS to view steampipe dashboard

Opening port 9194 on AWS didn't work

Comment: What operating system is your EC2 instance using?